# Add event listener is behaving weird?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onclicklistener

```
<section class="game--section">
        <div class="game-space">
            <div class="box box1 active-box"></div>
            <div class="box box2"></div>
            <div class="box box3"></div>
            <div class="box box4"></div>
            <div class="box box5"></div>
            <div class="box box6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="restart-button"></div>
    </section>
```

I have a div(.game-space) containing 6 child boxes, one of them is active box having ('.active-Box) class having green background,

1. so when I click on active box its shift its class(.active-Box) to the next box that gives green background in this way it goes to all the way to last Box.

and also I have restart button , when I click on it, the game should restart like the the active-box class gets tagged to first box and from here it shift again to the next class and goes to all the way to end Box by clicking.

But, Before clicking the restart button shifting between Box is linear going one by one, But after restart button is clicked the boxes are getting skipped and not shifting in linear skipping some boxes between,
WHY ? Any solution ?

[image]

```js
'use strict'
const allBox = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const activeBox = document.querySelector('.active-box')
const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart-button')
let active_box_index = activeBox_index_function();

slideBox(allBox[active_box_index]);

function slideBox(pass_active_box) {
  pass_active_box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    allBox[active_box_index].classList.remove('active-box')
    allBox[active_box_index + 1].classList.add('active-box')

    active_box_index = activeBox_index_function()
    slideBox(allBox[active_box_index]);
  })
}

console.log(allBox);

// active box index
function activeBox_index_function() {
  let index;
  allBox.forEach((el, indx) => {
    if (el.matches('.active-box')) {
      index = indx
    };
  })
  return index;
}

// when restart button clicked
restartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  allBox[active_box_index].classList.remove('active-box')
  allBox[0].classList.add('active-box')

  active_box_index = activeBox_index_function()
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,800&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/common-pixel');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.game--section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #252525;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.game-space {
  width: 80rem;
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.active-box {
  background-color: #099268;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.restart-button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="game--section">
    <div class="game-space">
      <div class="box box1 active-box"></div>
      <div class="box box2"></div>
      <div class="box box3"></div>
      <div class="box box4"></div>
      <div class="box box5"></div>
      <div class="box box6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="restart-button"></div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When the active box changes, you never remove the event listener from the previously active box. And when you go back to the beginning, you add multiple event listeners to the boxes.

Comment: Don't add event listeners incrementally like this. Add the listener to all the boxes, and have it check whether the clicked box is active. If it's not active, don't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you described is because of the accumulation of event listeners.

You may use the following code:

```
'use strict'
const allBox = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const activeBox = document.querySelector('.active-box')
const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart-button')
let active_box_index = activeBox_index_function();

slideBox(allBox[active_box_index]);

function myFunction(){
    allBox[active_box_index].classList.remove('active-box');
    if (!((active_box_index + 1)===allBox.length)){
    allBox[active_box_index + 1].classList.add('active-box');
    }
    allBox[active_box_index].removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
    active_box_index = activeBox_index_function();
    slideBox(allBox[active_box_index]);
}
  
function slideBox(pass_active_box) {
  if (!((active_box_index + 1)===allBox.length)){
  pass_active_box.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
  }
}

console.log(allBox);

// active box index
function activeBox_index_function() {
  let index;
  allBox.forEach((el, indx) => {
    if (el.matches('.active-box')) {
      index = indx
    };
  })
  return index;
}

// when restart button clicked
restartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  allBox[active_box_index].classList.remove('active-box');
  allBox[0].classList.add('active-box');
  allBox[active_box_index].removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
  allBox[0].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  active_box_index = activeBox_index_function()
})
```

The changes are:

- Added [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

and couple of other bug fixes:

- Passing class and adding event listener only if it is not the last box. You may set the first box as active-box after last box if you want so. Just add a `else` statement and add `allBox[0].classList.add('active-box');` inside it.
  Similarly don't forget to add event listener too....

Hope you find this useful!

Edit: I just found out that we don't have to add `removeEventListener()` if we define the function. This is because If the function is already in the list of event listeners for this target, the function is not added a second time. But when we call event listener with anonymous function, it is added second time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76139661/21598034) and [MDN Web Docs about addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: can I do this without separately defining myFunction(), but Just calling addEventListener('click' , function (){...}) ?

Comment: I see that, when I removed myfunction() and add that function directly inside the event gives me error, ? WHY ?

Comment: If you add function directly to the `addEventListener()` as an anonymous function, you have add the same code to the `removeEventListener()`. This is because the engine has to understand which function to remove from event listener. Instead I chose to add it as a named function to avoid repeating code and to save some keystrokes.

Comment: Your code is even working without removeEventListener();

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/charan123zxc/51xzy9p8/17/#collaborate&togetherjs=IuMpyfqmNN  ,have a look into the fiddle where I set comments of code1 and code2, code1 is same code as above where boxes gets skipped because of multiple incremented event triggers, but in code2 where all the anonymous function code is defined separately in sliderfunction() function and called when event fires, when though whether the anonymous or defined sliderfunction() have same code block, they are working differently on event triggers, after restart is clicked....

Comment: See this [MDN Web Docs][1].
It says: 
> If a particular anonymous function is in the list of event listeners
> registered for a certain target, and then later in the code, an
> identical anonymous function is given in an addEventListener call, the
> second function will also be added to the list of event listeners for
> that target.
> Indeed, anonymous functions are not identical even if defined using
> the same unchanging source-code called repeatedly, even if in a loop.

 


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: It seems that if the function is a named function, it is not added again to the event listener when you try to add again, but anonymous functions are truly anonymous and the engine can't identify it even if the same code is used so multiple similar event listeners are being added. Visit [MDN Web Docs][1] for more information.
 [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: It also points out that you cannot call `removeEventListener()` to an anonymous function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253392/discussion-between-adasgh-and-cooding-space).